# @sql error al hacer PIVOT Dinamico

Tags: sql, pivot

Buen Dia al querer ejecutar un Pivot de una tabla dinamica sale este error en  este query
Nose si tenga algo que ver el tipo de dato que es fecha ya que es datetime
:

```
 DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);
 SET @sql = N'
 SELECT
   * 
  FROM
  (  
    SELECT Cuenta
         , Nombre
         , Monto
         , Fecha
         ,Clasificación
 FROM Balanzas
  ) AS T
  PIVOT   
  (

  FOR Fecha IN (' + (SELECT STUFF(
 (
 SELECT
   ',' + QUOTENAME(LTRIM(Fecha))
 FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT Fecha
    FROM Balanzas
   ) AS T
 ORDER BY
 Fecha
 FOR XML PATH('')
 ), 1, 1, '')) + N')
  ) AS P;';
```

me sale el siguiente error y quisiera saber a que se debe
Gracias de antemano
[image]

Comment: Estás ejecutando todo el script?

Comment: Culpa mía , ya actualice la imagen del error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta agregar la función de agregado que quieres usar. Por los nombres, supongo que quieres mostrar la suma de los montos por fechas.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);
 SET @sql = N'
 SELECT
   * 
  FROM
  (  
    SELECT Cuenta
         , Nombre
         , Monto
         , Fecha
         ,Clasificación
 FROM Balanzas
  ) AS T
  PIVOT   
  (
  SUM(Monto)
  FOR Fecha IN (' + (SELECT STUFF(
 (
 SELECT
   ',' + QUOTENAME(LTRIM(Fecha))
 FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT Fecha
    FROM Balanzas
   ) AS T
 ORDER BY
 Fecha
 FOR XML PATH('')
 ), 1, 1, '')) + N')
  ) AS P;'; 
  
  EXECUTE ( @sql);
```

Comment: Crack!!,Gracias.